# Reshaping this pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

My current dataframe:

> Year CityA CityB

```
    Year    Abilene, TX Akron, OH   Albany, GA  Albany, OR  

0   2012    141.997500  92.033333   105.662500  116.250833  

1   2013    150.175000  95.971667   109.942500  125.361667  

2   2014    157.588333  98.930833   109.628333  132.511667  

3   2015    161.584167  102.416667  109.717500  142.058333  

4   2016    168.106667  107.449167  110.175833  157.204167
```

I want to reshape it preferably in-place in the following manner:

> `Year City Value'

```
Year  City         Value
2012 Abilene, TX, somevalue
2013 Abilene, TX, somevalue
```

For every city.

How do I go about this in an efficient manner?

Comment: Look at using `pd.DataFrame.melt` or `pd.wide_to_long`, it is hard to tell which should be used for your situation here

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your data, try and paste the data in the question that can be copied.

Comment: @NYCCoder I am sorry, what is the best way to go about that?

Comment: Just edit your question and paste the data there.

Comment: Thank you,  just did. 

@ScottBoston, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

`pd.melt(DataFrame, id_vars = "Year", value_vars = DataFrame.columns[1:])`

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston!